# Angular 2 RC.5 Shared Module can't find pipes

Tags: angular, angular-module

I'm updating my app to use a module structure and I ran into a weird issue when trying to add my pipe component into a shared module. From what I've read I have everything set up right, so I must be missing something little.

Error: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'cmgTitleize' could not be found`

I have a `BrowseModule`, this module declares a `ProjectCardComponent` which has a template that uses the `cmgTitleize` pipe. To provide access to the `TitleizePipe` I import my `SharedModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    ProjectCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})

export class BrowseModule { }
```

The `SharedModule`, imports the `PipesModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    PipesModule
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

`PipesModule` declares and exports the `TitelizePipe`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    TitleizePipe
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    TitleizePipe
  ]
})

export class PipesModule { }
```

Lastly for a sanity check heres the TitleizePipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'cmgTitleize'
})

export class TitleizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to also export the `PipesModule` in the `SharedModule`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the static "forRoot()" in a shared module, you still need to export the pipes or any other required module:

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        MyPipesModule                   //<---------------- HERE
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { 
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                MySingletonServices
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

And then you just import it in your main app module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule.forRoot()       // <------------
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: is `.forRoot()` method still applicable as of Angular 4+? I heard it's deprecated ?